# Ruby one liner to match multiple lines

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a text file that has the following content.

```
one two three
four five six
seven eight nine
ten eleven twelve
```

I am trying to convert the following Ruby code to a Ruby one liner command where it replace two lines (four five six and seven eight nine) with empty space.

```
input = File.new('./test', 'r+')
content = input.read
input.close

modified = content.sub("four five six\nseven eight nine", "")
print modified
```

I tried something like this but no luck.

```
ruby -pe 'gsub(/four five six\nseven eight nine/,"")' < ./test
```

Any idea?  Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps a regex "or" would help: `/(four five six|seven eight nine)/`.  In a case like this on the command line, it is often the case that the file will be read line-by-line.

Comment: Why a "one-liner"? That's an artificial constraint and might not be the best way. Do you want "empty space" or do you want to truncate the matched text? You're truncating but say you want "empty space" which is a nebulous term. And, why not just use `sed`, which will run a heck of a lot faster?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `-p` flag causes Ruby to "assume 'while gets(); ... end' loop around your script" (from `ruby -h`), thus running the command on each line separately, and then print the output. Instead, do an explicit [`gets(nil)`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-gets) to cause it to take in the whole input at once, then call `puts` on that (and add another `\n` at the end of the regex so it doesn't leave a blank line):

```
ruby -e 'puts gets(nil).gsub(/four five six\nseven eight nine\n/,"")' < ./test
one two three
ten eleven twelve
```

Answer (score 2):

Quick sanity check; Ruby matches newlines without a problem:

```
2.0.0-p195 :159 > /abc\ndef/ === "abc\ndef"
 => true
```

There are some caveats (use the `m` modifier if you want `.` to match `\n`!)

```
2.0.0-p195 :161 > /.{7}/ === "abc\ndef"
 => false 
2.0.0-p195 :162 > /.{7}/m === "abc\ndef"
 => true
```

Perhaps you have some whitespace or something at the ends of your lines, so take that into account in your regex (`/four five six\s*\nseven eight nine/m`)

Answer (score 1):

Try a regex "or": `/(four five six|seven eight nine)/`.  In a case like this on the command line, it is often the case that the file will be read line-by-line.